# How to build an an address label from multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have some fields that form an address, which for the sake of argument has 5 address lines:

```
line1,
line2,
line3,
line4,
line5.
```

All of which are their own column in the table.

Is there a way within mysql to express this as one memo field as an address label? (with linebreaks)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Comment: Look for mysql string concat.

Comment: yes but how do these work with line breaks, dont want it to be one long text field, need it to be a memo box with address lines per line

Comment: did you both to read the link i provided? `SELECT CONCAT_WS('<br>',` ...

Comment: Ok got that working, thanks, how about if i wanted to ignore null lines, so say for example, if addressline4 was black, i wouldnt get a space between 3 and 5

Comment: this is what i want to avoid prntscr.com/69su5r

Comment: mysql or php or both - you decide

Comment: at the moment im doing it through a mysql query, see prntscr.com/69svfy

Comment: seen this, any good? CONCAT_WS(' ', NULLIF(field1, ''), NULLIF(field2, ''), NULLIF(field3, ''));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
concat_ws('<br>',
        IF(LENGTH(`address1`),`address1`,NULL),
        IF(LENGTH(`address2`),`address2`,NULL),
        IF(LENGTH(`address3`),`address3`,NULL)

)
```

Comment: well you never told us what kind of line breaks you wanted, so i guessed

Comment: seriously a big thank you, been struggling with that for 6 months